# WxPython: How to display any message window for a fixed time them let it automatically disappear

Tags: python, wxpython, python-2.7

I am designing a software using **python** and **Wxpython** for *GUI works*. I want to display a message to user for a fixed amount of time then let it dissapear automatically.
I unable to figure out how to do this.
Plz Help...
Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use wx.BusyInfo or wx.lib.agw.pybusyinfo. Here's a sample that shows a non-modal message for 3 seconds.  To get rid of the messagebox dialog, simply set its name ref to None.

```
import time

import wx
import wx.lib.agw.pybusyinfo as PBI

def showmsg():
    app = wx.App(redirect=False)
    msg = 'this is a test'
    title = 'Message!'
    d = PBI.PyBusyInfo(msg, title=title)
    return d    

if __name__ == '__main__':
    d = showmsg()
    time.sleep(3)
    d = None
```

good luck,
Mike

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should work:

```
import threading

msgbox = wx.MessageBox('Hey user, there is something I want to tell you!', 
                       'Alert', wx.ICON_EXCLAMATION | wx.STAY_ON_TOP)
threading.Timer(10.0, msgbox.EndModal).start()
```

I don't have the opportunity to test it now, but I think it is the general idea that matters.

Comment: It will not work, you need to create `wx.App` first.